# Replacing Computers on Windows AD domain with same name

Tags: windows, active-directory

If I have a laptop with name XYZ on a Windows AD domain, and I image a new laptop to replace the old one, is there a way to replace the old laptop with the new one in AD so that it can keep the same name?

Currently the only way it seems to be possible is either remove the old one from the domain first, or rename the new one after I remove the old one.

What I want is to be able to join the domain and have it replace that computer's AD object at the same time.

Is this possible?

Comment: I think you have to remove the old one first.

Comment: You indeed have to remove the old one first. You cannot give any AD object the properties of another object, because there are hidden ID's involved that seriously mess up things. AD has protection against it, and if you go really deep to try and make it work, you most often make things a lot worse. Just rename the old computer first, or remove it from the domain if renaming is not possible anymore. Also the powershell command `rename-computer`, executed on the target pc will manage Active Directory, while renaming the computer from the System properties will not.